# How to use store excel file in localpath using cron job in laravel?

Tags: laravel, cron

I am using Laravel 5.7 and Windows scheduler for cron job. I want to store the excel file using cron job. How can I achieve that?

I have used `Excel::store()` method. But it only works when I click on button. How can I achieve that using cron job?

I tried using this code:

```
protected $signature = 'excel:attendance';

protected $description = 'Using smart office excel for attendance';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    Excel::store(new attendanceExcel(),'Dummy_excel_cronjob.xlsx');
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean its not working? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Did you run `php artisan schedule:run`?

Comment: You need to create laravel command to run with cron. There is great tutorial for that https://appdividend.com/2018/03/01/laravel-cronjob-scheduling-tutorial/ starting from step 3

Comment: Thanks @VolodymyrSitdikov. But I am using the Windows task scheduler to run cron jobs. So I have specified the command to run over there. Other things like sending emails, storing data in DB are working in this cron job. Only I am not able to generate and store the excel file through cron job.